# What is in Clang Tools Extras?

Tags: c++, c, clang

I build Clang from sources to ensure I get the latest analysis tools and sanitizers. The tarballs I download are Clang Source Code, LLVM Source Code, Compiler-RT Source Code and LLDB Source Code. The [LLVM Download Page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html) also lists a [Clang Tools Extra](http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/clang-tools-extra-3.4.src.tar.gz) download.

What is in Clang Tools Extra tarball?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it in the official documentation:
[extra clang tools documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/)

Comment: Thanks Mansuro. It appears the project changed the title of the page to "Extra Clang Tools...". from the name of the file. That would explain the five search results I got back.

Comment: Mansuro - the `modularize` tools looks interesting. I downloaded the extra tools, but its not clear to me how to build it. Does extra tools get unpacked into `llvm-3.4.2.src/tools`; or does it get unpacked into `llvm-3.4.2.src/projects`?

Comment: @jww it has to be in the `tools/extra` subdirectory, according to the included `README` file

Comment: So not clang-format?